# How does $resource in Angular work

Tags: angularjs, rest

If I have a url like this "http : // x.x.x.x:port"

```
app.factory("myservice", function($resource){
    var res = function(){
        return $resource("http://x.x.x.x:port/profile/:userID", {
               {
                 getUserInfo: {
                                method: "GET",
                                params: {userID : "userNumber"},
                                headers:{
                                       "Accept": "application/json",
                                       "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                       sessionID : "sesionIDNumber"
                                }
                              }

                },
        });
    }

    console.log( res.get("firstName") );//error GET http://myurl/myport/profile?0=l&1=a&2=s&3=t&4=n&5=a&6=m&7=e&reg=%7B%2…2Fjson%22,%22sessionId%22:%22b1bfa646-215e-4223-be8c-b53d578ba379%22%7D%7D 404 (Not Found) 

});
```

If I want to get the user's infoes, what do I have to do?

Comment: the docs have a good example of this - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Also a video tutorial: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-resource-for-data-models

Comment: I've seen the documentation, but I didn't understand something.
If my code is right, what it's going to be the result (return)

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
app.factory("myservice", function($resource)
{
 return $resource('http://x.x.x.x:port/profile/:userID/:sessionID', {
        userID : '@userID'
        sessionID: "@sessionID"
        }); 
});
```

A best example is shown below

```
app.factory('Books', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    return $resource( '/book/:bookId', 
        { bookId: '@bookId' }, { 
            loan: { 
                method: 'PUT', 
                params: { bookId: '@bookId' }, 
                isArray: false 
            } 
            /* , method2: { ... } */
        } );
}]);
```

At this point it is really simple to send requests to the web service, that we build in the previous post.Everywhere it is possible to inject the Books service it is possible to write:

```
postData = { 
  "id": 42, 
  "title": "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", 
  "authors": ["Douglas Adams"] 
}
Books.save({}, postData);
// It sends a POST request to /book. 
// postData are the additional post data

Books.get({bookId: 42});
// Get data about the book with id = 42

Books.query();
// It is still a GET request, but it points to /book, 
// so it is used to get the data about all the books

Books.loan({bookId: 42});
// It is a custom action.
// Update the data of the book with id = 42

Books.delete({bookId: 42});
// Delete data about the book with id = 42
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because I got an error: 500 (Failed to invoke handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.sce.demo.controller.UserProfileController.fecth(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing header 'sessionId' of type [java.lang.String])